# How do I make a button image add one to a variable on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

How do I make a button image change a variable +1 on click?
~John

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.We recommend to refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show some attempts you've made and we'll try to help you. Why have you tagged `cookies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="addOne()">ADD</button><br/>
<button onclick="getCounter()">PRINT</button>
</body>
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function addOne(){
        counter++;
    }

    function getCounter(){
        console.log(counter);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Using something like an onclick event you can call a function to increment the value of a variable.

Comment: Sort of what I meant but I wanted to be able to click the image.